# How to transition to route in Ember from global context?

Tags: ember.js, google-chrome-extension

I am integrating a chrome extension with an ember app. I have some chrome extension code in my app.js file:

```
window.sendToExtension = (message, callback) => {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extensionId, message, (response) => {
    console.log('got response from extension!!', response)
    if (response.path) {
      //Here I need to tell the ember app the transition to the given path
    }
  })
}
```

`this` refers to `window` so I can't just call `this.transitionTo`. How can I transition to the route name the extension has told me to?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out!! All I had to do was add a `beforeModel` hook to the application route that did `window.applicationRouteInstance = this` and then I can access this globally, such as in my extension messaging code, to do `applicationRouteInstance.transitionTo(response.path)`

Also there's the new App.visit api coming in 2.3